# Can not run model with TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, kaggle, tpu

I am constructing a model using EfficientNet in order to predict age an gender. I am using the images from UTKFace. I am doing it using kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/jangedoo/utkface-new

I am running the TPU using kaggle notebook with accelerator TPU V3-8

I was using GPU and I was not having any problem executing my code. I would like to run it using TPU, but I am getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
##IMPORTS
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import seaborn as sns
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB0
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras import utils
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
import math

##DEFINE VARIABLES
DIR_UTKFace="../input/utkface-new/UTKFace"
IMG_HEIGHT = 224
IMG_WIDTH = 224
BATCH_SIZE = 8
EPOCHS = 10

##USE TPU
try:
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
    print('Running on TPU ', tpu.master())
except ValueError:
    print("Could not connect to TPU")
    tpu = None
if tpu:
    try:
        print("initializing TPU ...")
        tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
        tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
        strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
        print("TPU initialized")
    except _:
        print("failed to initialize TPU")


#AUTO = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
#REPLICAS = strategy.num_replicas_in_sync
#print(f'REPLICAS: {REPLICAS}')

##GET DATAFRAME
#For gender we get a numeric value. Male = 0, Female = 1
GENDER_MAP=['M','F']

#Get age and gender from image file name
def get_info_from_image(image_file_name):
    age=int(image_file_name.split('_')[0])
    gender=int(image_file_name.split('_')[1])
    return age, gender

#we generate a dataframe with the information we need: age, gender, file name.
all_ages = []
all_genders = []
all_file_names = []

files_names=os.listdir(DIR_UTKFace)
for file_name in files_names:

    #check that all images are jpg format
    if ".jpg" not in file_name:
        raise RuntimeError("Format not expected: "+ file_name)

    age, gender = get_info_from_image(file_name)

    all_ages.append(age)
    all_genders.append(gender)
    all_file_names.append(file_name)


dataset_images = {'age': all_ages, 
                  'gender': all_genders, 
                  'file_name': all_file_names}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset_images)

##SPLIT DATA
maxAge = df['age'].max()
TRAIN_TEST_SPLIT = 0.8  
TRAIN_VALID_SPLIT = 0.7
p = np.random.permutation(len(df)) 
train_up_to = int(len(df) * TRAIN_TEST_SPLIT)
train_idx = p[:train_up_to]
test_idx = p[train_up_to:]

train_up_to = int(train_up_to * TRAIN_VALID_SPLIT)
train_idx, valid_idx = train_idx[:train_up_to], train_idx[train_up_to:]

##CUSTOM DATA GENERATOR
def get_data_generator(df, indices, is_train):

    images = list()
    ages = list()
    genders = list()
    while True:
        for i in indices:
            r = df.iloc[i]
            file, age, gender = r['file_name'], r['age'], r['gender']
            img_dir=DIR_UTKFace+'/'+file
            im = Image.open(img_dir)
            im = im.resize((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH))
            im = np.array(im) / 255.0
            images.append(im)
            ages.append(age / maxAge) 
            genders.append(to_categorical(gender, 2))  
            if len(images) >= BATCH_SIZE:
                print(len(images))
                yield np.asarray(images), [np.asarray(ages), np.asarray(genders)]
                images = list()
                ages = list()
                genders = list()
            #discards the remainder                                               
        if len(images) > 0:
                images = list()
                ages = list()
                genders = list()


#DEFINE MODEL
efficient_net = EfficientNetB0(
    weights='imagenet',  
    include_top=False, 
    input_shape=(224,224, 3),
    pooling='max'
)


base_model = models.Sequential()
base_model.add(efficient_net)
features=base_model.output 

age_output = Dense(units=maxAge, activation="softmax", name="age_output")(features)
gender_output = Dense(units=2, activation="sigmoid", name="gender_output")(features)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=[age_output, gender_output])

model.compile(optimizer = "adam", 
              loss={'age_output': 'mse', 'gender_output': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
              metrics={'age_output': 'mae', 'gender_output': 'accuracy'},
              loss_weights={'age_output': 2., 'gender_output': 1.})

train_gen = get_data_generator(df, train_idx, True)
valid_gen = get_data_generator(df, valid_idx, False)

def get_steps(lenght_samples, batch_size):
    if (lenght_samples % batch_size) > 0 :
        return (lenght_samples // batch_size) + 1
    else :
        return lenght_samples // batch_size

steps_train = get_steps(len(train_idx), BATCH_SIZE)
steps_valid = get_steps(len(valid_idx), BATCH_SIZE)

hist = model.fit(train_gen,
                 steps_per_epoch=steps_train,
                 epochs=EPOCHS,
                 verbose=1,
                 validation_steps=steps_valid,
                 validation_data=valid_gen
                 )
```

It is in the last part of the code where I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnavailableError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_43/3634844859.py in <module>
      8                  callbacks = [callbacks, early],
      9                  validation_steps=steps_valid,
---> 10                  validation_data=valid_gen
     11                  )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1103               logs = tmp_logs  # No error, now safe to assign to logs.
   1104               end_step = step + data_handler.step_increment
-> 1105               callbacks.on_train_batch_end(end_step, logs)
   1106               if self.stop_training:
   1107                 break

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs)
    452     """
    453     if self._should_call_train_batch_hooks:
--> 454       self._call_batch_hook(ModeKeys.TRAIN, 'end', batch, logs=logs)
    455 
    456   def on_test_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in _call_batch_hook(self, mode, hook, batch, logs)
    294       self._call_batch_begin_hook(mode, batch, logs)
    295     elif hook == 'end':
--> 296       self._call_batch_end_hook(mode, batch, logs)
    297     else:
    298       raise ValueError('Unrecognized hook: {}'.format(hook))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in _call_batch_end_hook(self, mode, batch, logs)
    314       self._batch_times.append(batch_time)
    315 
--> 316     self._call_batch_hook_helper(hook_name, batch, logs)
    317 
    318     if len(self._batch_times) >= self._num_batches_for_timing_check:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in _call_batch_hook_helper(self, hook_name, batch, logs)
    354       hook = getattr(callback, hook_name)
    355       if getattr(callback, '_supports_tf_logs', False):
--> 356         hook(batch, logs)
    357       else:
    358         if numpy_logs is None:  # Only convert once.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs)
   1018 
   1019   def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
-> 1020     self._batch_update_progbar(batch, logs)
   1021 
   1022   def on_test_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in _batch_update_progbar(self, batch, logs)
   1082     if self.verbose == 1:
   1083       # Only block async when verbose = 1.
-> 1084       logs = tf_utils.to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
   1085       self.progbar.update(self.seen, list(logs.items()), finalize=False)
   1086 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py in to_numpy_or_python_type(tensors)
    512     return t  # Don't turn ragged or sparse tensors to NumPy.
    513 
--> 514   return nest.map_structure(_to_single_numpy_or_python_type, tensors)
    515 
    516 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    657 
    658   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 659       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    660       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    661 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    657 
    658   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 659       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    660       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    661 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py in _to_single_numpy_or_python_type(t)
    508   def _to_single_numpy_or_python_type(t):
    509     if isinstance(t, ops.Tensor):
--> 510       x = t.numpy()
    511       return x.item() if np.ndim(x) == 0 else x
    512     return t  # Don't turn ragged or sparse tensors to NumPy.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in numpy(self)
   1069     """
   1070     # TODO(slebedev): Consider avoiding a copy for non-CPU or remote tensors.
-> 1071     maybe_arr = self._numpy()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1072     return maybe_arr.copy() if isinstance(maybe_arr, np.ndarray) else maybe_arr
   1073 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _numpy(self)
   1037       return self._numpy_internal()
   1038     except core._NotOkStatusException as e:  # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 1039       six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, e.message), None)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1040 
   1041   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

UnavailableError: {{function_node __inference_train_function_18204}} failed to connect to all addresses
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0:
:{"created":"@1637743656.593666229","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":4143,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1637743656.593647082","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]
```

I do not have any idea what is happening. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: where is this tpu? where is the code running?

Comment: I am running the TPU using Kaggle notebook with accelerator TPU V3-8

Answer (score 0):

As of now Kaggle and Colab only support remote TPU Devices which prevents TPUs to access your local files or run a custom Python image generator code.

New [TPU-VM](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/introducing-cloud-tpu-vms) architecture solves that issue by attaching the TPUs to the host VM. It will be supported in Kaggle and Colab soon.

Meanwhile, as a workaround you can move your data to a GCS bucket and use
[`tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory) or [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) and combining it with Keras preprocessing [layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing).